# Mssql Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'. Yii2 migration

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

```
    return 'nvarchar(255)'
        .($notNull ? ' NOT NULL' : '')
        .' CHECK ('.$fieldName." IN('".implode("', '", $values)."'))"
        .($default ? " DEFAULT '".$default."'" : '');

 CONSOLE: > alter column role in table user to nvarchar(255) NOT NULL CHECK (role IN('DES1', 'DES2', 'DES12', 'IM1', 'Gateway'
, 'Read-Only', 'Admin')) DEFAULT 'DES1'
```

Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Se
rver]

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'.

The SQL being executed was:

```
ALTER TABLE [user] 
ALTER COLUMN [role] nvarchar(255) NOT NULL CHECK (role IN('DES1', 'DES2','DES12', 'IM1', 'Gateway', 'Read-Only', 'Admin')) 
  DEFAULT 'DES1'
```

(E:....\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:6

Comment: Is there already a check constraint or a default value on this column when you run this alter statement ? If so you might need to get rid of them first

Comment: execute SQL: ALTER TABLE "user" DROP CONSTRAINT CK__user__role__589CF14A ... done (time: 0.004s)

Comment: The problem is that I already have a validation rule CHECK, I delete it and then create a new one.

Comment: So your problem is solved now ?